# Using \multido with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks-add

Consider the following example:

**Code**

```
% xelatex filename.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-poly,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\radius{5 }
\def\factorA{\calc{(1/10*(5+5^(1/2)))^(1/2)*\radius}}
\def\factorB{\calc{1/2*(3+5^(1/2))}}
\def\factorC{\calc{\factorA*\factorB}}
%\def\firstcoor{\calc{5/4*(5^(1/2)-1)*\factorB}}
%\def\secondcoor{\calc{1/4*(10*(5+5^(1/2)))^(1/2)*\factorB}}
\def\dist{\calc{(1/10*(5-5^(1/2)))^(1/2)*\factorB*\radius}}
\def\firstcoorA{\calc{\dist*cos(3/10*pi)}}
\def\secondcoorA{\calc{\dist*sin(3/10*pi)}}
\def\firstcoorB{\calc{\dist*cos(7/10*pi)}}
\def\secondcoorB{\calc{\dist*sin(7/10*pi)}}
\def\firstcoorC{\calc{\dist*cos(11/10*pi)}}
\def\secondcoorC{\calc{\dist*sin(11/10*pi)}}
\def\firstcoorD{\calc{\dist*cos(15/10*pi)}}
\def\secondcoorD{\calc{\dist*sin(15/10*pi)}}
\def\firstcoorE{\calc{\dist*cos(19/10*pi)}}
\def\secondcoorE{\calc{\dist*sin(19/10*pi)}}

\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-10.7,-11.2)(10.7,9)
{\psset{%
  linewidth=2\pslinewidth,%
  linecolor=green!90!yellow!70!blue!70,%
  fillstyle=solid,%
  fillcolor=green!60!yellow!80!blue!80%
 }
 \rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorA]}
 \rput{ 36}(\firstcoorA,\secondcoorA){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorA]}
 \rput{ 36}(\firstcoorB,\secondcoorB){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorA]}
 \rput{ 36}(\firstcoorC,\secondcoorC){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorA]}
 \rput{180}(\firstcoorD,\secondcoorD){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorA]}
 \rput{ 36}(\firstcoorE,\secondcoorE){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorA]}
}
 \rput{180}(0,0){\PstPentagon[unit=\factorC,linewidth=2\pslinewidth]}
 \rput(!0.8 \radius mul neg 0.26 \radius mul neg){\num{\radius}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

How do I use the `\multido` command to draw the five green pentagons around the center one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poly}  
\begin{document}
\def\Radius{2 } \def\myCoor{}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psset{linewidth=2\pslinewidth,%
  linecolor=green!90!yellow!70!blue!70,%
  fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!60!yellow!80!blue!80}
 \rput(0,0){\PstPentagon[unit=\Radius]}
 \pstVerb{/R1 \Radius 36 cos mul dup add def /R2 R1 \Radius add def }
 \multido{\iA=-90+72}{5}{%
   \xdef\myCoor{\myCoor(!R2 \iA\space PtoC)} %
   \rput{36}(! R1 \iA\space PtoC){\PstPentagon[unit=\Radius]}}
 \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1.5pt,fillstyle=none}
 \expandafter\pspolygon\myCoor
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, Herbert! (Btw. what have you edited? I copied the code before the edit.)

Comment: deleted an empty line :-)

Comment: Have you made another change to the code? (I haven't been on TeX Stack Exchange for a couple of days and now the code looks different from what I have, I think.) If so, would you give a short explanation of what it is good for?

Comment: click on the  "edite 2 dyas ago" and you'll see the changes

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what this new code does compared to the old one?

Comment: it is shorter ...